# Make plot smoother in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I'm trying to plot a function using pgfplots:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}

\newcommand{\param}{2.0}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}[view={40}{50}]
            \addplot3[surf, domain = 0:1, y domain = 0:1, unbounded coords=jump,
            samples = 50]
            {x^(-\param-1)*y^(-\param-1)*(x^(-\param)+y^(-\param)-1)^(-1/\param-2)+\param*x^(-\param-1)*y^(-\param-1)*(x^(-\param)+y^(-\param)-1)^(-1/\param-2)};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image: Pgfplots output]

Compared with (plotted in the OS X Grapher application)

[image: OS X grapher output]

the plot generated by pgfplots is a lot "rougher" near `x=y=0`. I have tried increasing the number of samples from the default to 50 but that hasn't really improved the plot much.

Comment: you need to increase both axis sample number such as `samples = 50, samples y= 50`

Comment: I've just tried `samples = 70, samples y = 70` - it doesn't seem to have any visible effect.

Comment: Your last term is power of a power or typo?

Comment: Use Gnuplot. I find that it handles surface plots better than pgfplots.

Comment: @percusse The last term is not a power of a power. What makes you think it might be (I can't spot any typo)?

Comment: You have a^b^c form.

Comment: I don't see anything of the form a^b^c. The last term is of the form (a^(-c)+y^(-c)-1)^((-1/c)-2). It's a sum raised to a power.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default surface plot of `pgfplots` uses two triangles for each rectangular patch segment. Usually, the diagonal does not matter much -- but in this case, it really matters and the result is unsuitable.

Note that `shader=interp` appears to select the other diagonal (unintentionally, but it does). A simple solution would be to add `shader=interp`, unless you really need the grid lines.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}

\newcommand{\param}{2.0}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}[view={40}{50}]
            \addplot3[surf, domain = 0:1, y domain = 0:1, unbounded coords=jump,
                shader=interp,
                samples = 25]
            {x^(-\param-1)*y^(-\param-1)*(x^(-\param)+y^(-\param)-1)^(-1/\param-2)+\param*x^(-\param-1)*y^(-\param-1)*(x^(-\param)+y^(-\param)-1)^(-1/\param-2)};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This answer is now an appendix (how to add gridlines) to C.F.'s (better) answer above: `shader=interp` is the `surf` equivalent of `smooth`, and it preserves the color scheme, unlike my original answer.

`shader=interp` removes gridlines, but you add some of them back in, because of the above fact, thus:

[image: C.F.'s answer plus gridlines]

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{pgfplots}\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\newcommand{\pt}{2}
\begin{document}\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[3d box,width=8cm,view={147}{56},
    domain=0:0.4,y domain=0:0.4,samples=32,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,zlabel={$z$},]
    \addplot3[surf,domain=0:0.4,y domain=0:0.4,unbounded coords=jump,shader=interp]
{%
x^(-\pt-1)*y^(-\pt-1)*(x^(-\pt)+y^(-\pt)-1)^(-1/\pt-2)+\pt*x^(-\pt-1)*y^(-\pt-1)*(x^(-\pt)+y^(-\pt)-1)^(-1/\pt-2)%
};
    \addplot3[domain=0:0.4,y domain=0:0.4,unbounded coords=jump,smooth]
{%
x^(-\pt-1)*y^(-\pt-1)*(x^(-\pt)+y^(-\pt)-1)^(-1/\pt-2)+\pt*x^(-\pt-1)*y^(-\pt-1)*(x^(-\pt)+y^(-\pt)-1)^(-1/\pt-2)%
};
\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}
```

The gridlines themselves are:

[image: smooth no surf]

Smoothing via cubic bézier curves is implemented in pgfplots. (See p.76 of [the pgfplots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf).)

`\addplot3[...,smooth,...]` for line only or `\addplot+[...,smooth,...]` gives the above and fill it with blue points.

Consider

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[view={40}{50}]
        \addplot3 [y domain = 0:2,smooth]{-0.7+4*exp(-0.5*(x+3))*(3*cos(4*x*180/pi)+2.5*cos(2*x*180/pi))+0.5*y*y*4};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: gliding]

and compare to unsmoothed version

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[view={40}{50}]
        \addplot3 [y domain = 0:2]{-0.7+4*exp(-0.5*(x+3))*(3*cos(4*x*180/pi)+2.5*cos(2*x*180/pi))+0.5*y*y*4};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: nongliding]

True, there is a problem with color. The equation in the question is 1/x^5*1/y^3+ 2/x^5*1/y^3+2*y^(9/2) reduced. It's very sharp and using 256 samples for example instead causes main memory to run out and TeX halts compiling... Smooth with around 100 samples and rotating the view may be the only option, when used with a compatible color scheme to return the surface fill.

Comment: smooth is not a good idea for closed form plotting. Not only it makes the plot wrong but also often introduces wrong color schemes

Answer (score 2):

Just for showing another plotting approach, here is the LaTeX-R-knitr solution.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[scale=2.5]
<<>>=
library(lattice)
param<-2
x<-seq(0,1,len=30)
y<-seq(0,1,len=30)
g<-expand.grid(x=x,y=y)
g$z<-(g$x^(-param-1)*g$y^(-param-1)*(g$x^(-param)
     +g$y^(-param)-1)^(-1/param-2)+param*g$x^(-param-1)*g$y^(-param-1)*(g$x^(-param)
     +g$y^(-param)-1)^(-1/param-2))
wireframe(z~x*y,g,drape=TRUE,aspect=c(1,1),colorkey=TRUE
          ,screen = list(x=-40,y=-60,z=-45))
@
%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]